# Почему виджет никак не отображается на MainWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ниже код Основного окна и файла запуска:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import random


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(680, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.CurrentPlayer_LineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.CurrentPlayer_LineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 180, 20))
        self.CurrentPlayer_LineEdit.setObjectName("CurrentPlayer_LineEdit")
        self.CurrentPlayer_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CurrentPlayer_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 180, 16))
        self.CurrentPlayer_Label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.CurrentPlayer_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.CurrentPlayer_Label.setObjectName("CurrentPlayer_Label")
        self.SelectCurrentPlayer_PushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SelectCurrentPlayer_PushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 180, 25))
        self.SelectCurrentPlayer_PushButton.setObjectName("SelectCurrentPlayer_PushButton")
        self.GetStatistic_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.GetStatistic_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 180, 25))
        self.GetStatistic_pushButton.setObjectName("GetStatistic_pushButton")
        self.GetInstruction_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.GetInstruction_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 180, 25))
        self.GetInstruction_pushButton.setObjectName("GetInstruction_pushButton")
        self.LeadersBoard_tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.LeadersBoard_tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 180, 360))
        self.LeadersBoard_tableWidget.setObjectName("LeadersBoard_tableWidget")
        self.LeadersBoard_tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.LeadersBoard_tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.LeadersBoard_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LeadersBoard_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 180, 16))
        self.LeadersBoard_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.LeadersBoard_Label.setObjectName("LeadersBoard_Label")
        self.CurrentScore_LineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.CurrentScore_LineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 20, 80, 20))
        self.CurrentScore_LineEdit.setObjectName("CurrentScore_LineEdit")
        self.BestScore_LineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.BestScore_LineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 20, 80, 20))
        self.BestScore_LineEdit.setObjectName("BestScore_LineEdit")
        self.CurrentScore_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.CurrentScore_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 0, 80, 16))
        self.CurrentScore_Label.setObjectName("CurrentScore_Label")
        self.BestScore_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.BestScore_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 0, 80, 16))
        self.BestScore_Label.setObjectName("BestScore_Label")
        self.BackgroundForField_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.BackgroundForField_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 450, 450))
        self.BackgroundForField_Label.setText("")
        self.BackgroundForField_Label.setObjectName("BackgroundForField_Label")
        self.StartNewGame_PushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.StartNewGame_PushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(385, 60, 120, 25))
        self.StartNewGame_PushButton.setObjectName("StartNewGame_PushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 680, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.CurrentPlayer_LineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.CurrentScore_LineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.BestScore_LineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.BackgroundForField_Label.setPixmap(QPixmap('background.jpg'))
        self.StartNewGame_PushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_new_field)

    def create_new_field(self):
        self.field = [[None,None,None,None] for i in range(4)]
        self.add_new_plate()

    def add_new_plate(self):
        try:
            while True:
                x_pos = random.randint(0, 3)
                y_pos = random.randint(0, 3)
                if self.field[x_pos][y_pos] is None:
                    value_of_plate = str(random.choice([2, 4]))
                    self.field[x_pos][y_pos] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(value_of_plate,self.centralwidget)
                    self.field[x_pos][y_pos].setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(245 + x_pos * 90 + 10 * x_pos,
                                                                      125 + y_pos * 90 + 10 * y_pos,
                                                                      90, 90))
                    self.field[x_pos][y_pos].setEnabled(False)
                    break
                else:
                    x_pos = random.randint(0, 3)
                    y_pos = random.randint(0, 3)
        except BaseException:
            pass

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.add_new_plate()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Игра \"2048\""))
        self.CurrentPlayer_LineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите пользователя"))
        self.CurrentPlayer_Label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя текущего пользователя"))
        self.SelectCurrentPlayer_PushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать пользователя"))
        self.GetStatistic_pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.GetInstruction_pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Инструкция"))
        self.LeadersBoard_Label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Таблица лидеров"))
        self.CurrentScore_LineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.BestScore_LineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.CurrentScore_Label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Текущий счет:"))
        self.BestScore_Label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Лучший счет:"))
        self.StartNewGame_PushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать новую игру"))
```

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow


# Наследуемся от виджета из PyQt5.QtWidgets и от класса с интерфейсом
class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Вызываем метод для загрузки интерфейса из класса Ui_MainWindow,
        # остальное без изменений
        self.setupUi(self)
        

def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но если в файле основного окна добавить строку

```
self.field = [[None,None,None,None] for i in range(4)]
```

и код функции add_new_plate в конец функции setupUi, то кнопка отобразится.
При вызове add_new_plate, кнопка появляется в списке и имеет все заданные ей атрибуты, но на основном окне не отобразится

Comment: Оффтоп, не принято в `Ui_MainWindow` добавлять пользовательскую логику (`self.StartNewGame_PushButton.clicked.connect(self.create_new_field)`, `create_new_field`, `add_new_plate`, `keyPressEvent`), вообще в этом файле должен быть закомментированный текст про то, что файл сгенерирован и его ненужно менять :) Логику лучше перенести в `MyWidget`. А для размещения виджетов по сетке лучше используйте `QGridLayout`

Comment: В MyWidget планировал перенести по полной работоспособности проекта, а про `QGridLayout`постараюсь почитать.